# Multiplying a list of items from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and that contains a list of two numbers each. I need to multiply those numbers together and keep a running total for all keys in the dictionary. I keep getting a TypeError:

```
sub = v1 * v2
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

I have tried to cast it to float, but then I get:

```
v1= float(c.get(k,v[0]))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Code below:

```
change = {'penny': [.01,57], 'nickel':[.05,34],'dime':[.1,42], 'quarter':  [.25,19],'half dallar':[.5,3],'one dollar bill':[1,24],'five dollar bill':[5,7],'ten dollar bill':[10,5],'twenty dollar bill':[20,3]}

def totalAmount(c):
   total = 0
   for k, v in c.items():
       v1= c.get(k,v[0])
       v2= c.get(k,v[1])

       sub = v1 * v2
       total = total + sub


totalAmount(change)
print("Total in petty cash: $" + total)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v1= c.get(k,v[0])
v2= c.get(k,v[1])
```

In this situation `v1` and `v2` both get set to `v`. `c.get(i)` returns `c[i]`, so `c[k]` will naturally return the corresponding value `v`. Instead just split your list up like this:

```
v1, v2 = v
```

Comment: It worked thanks! had to move my last print statement inside the function and cast total to str()

Comment: @michaelwb11 glad to help!!! please consider marking as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the `dict.get` method is for default value, not for further value retrieval.

You can unpack the values of the sub-lists like this instead:

```
for k, (v1, v2) in c.items():
    sub = v1 * v2
    total = total + sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
change = {'penny': [.01,57], 'nickel':[.05,34],'dime':[.1,42], 'quarter':  [.25,19],'half dallar':[.5,3],'one dollar bill':[1,24],'five dollar bill':[5,7],'ten dollar bill':[10,5],'twenty dollar bill':[20,3]}

def totalAmount(c):
   total = 0
   for k, v in c.items():
       sub = v[0] * v[1]
       total = total + sub
   return total


t = totalAmount(change)
print(t)
```

output will be

```
181.72
```

and the problem with your code is `v1= c.get(k,v[0])`.
you should change it to `v1= c.get(k)[0]` if you want to use `get`, but when you use `.items()` you don't need to use `get`. `v` will be that desired array in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
[change[key][0]*change[key][1] for key in change.keys()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
total = sum(v1 * v2 for v1, v2 in change.values())
```